# Dynamic Reports Class not found exception

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I'm trying to test Dynamic Reports using code I got from another site, but it gives me the error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I've heard that this means that I haven't put in the proper jar files, but to my knowledge I have all of them in (see [here](https://puu.sh/wlXGM/eb3ea44551.png) and [here](https://puu.sh/wlXHB/398179d902.png)). [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/) is the site I got the code from.
If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit: Images-

[image]
`[image]

Comment: I don't see the MySQL connector in your referenced librariries. It should be named something like `mysql-connector-xxx.jar` Check your actual version of MySQL instance and provide the suitable connector to. As a side remark : please add the images in the question.

Comment: I added a file named mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin and now have the error "java.sql.SQLException: Illegal connection port value 'port'". Did I add the wrong file or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: It should rather be a `.jar` file... For the new problem : have you correctly configured your url connection to the DB  in your application ? Please show  relevant code.

Comment: Looks like @davidxxx suggestion solved your initial issue. Now you need to check your db connection url to ensure it's a valid one. It looks something like this `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blabla`

Comment: I fixed something and now the error I get is:
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 


`** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`


My connection code is
 
`connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql");`

but I'm not sure if that's correct. I've tried putting the name of my database there but I get the same error

Comment: Sounds like your db is not accessible. Try connecting to your db from console or `mysqladmin` just to verify that it's accessible before fixing your code.

Comment: Just to be clear, am I supposed to put the name of my database after the 3306/ ?